# Delayed expansion not working for a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch script and I am calling another batch script "Strip_Batch.bat" and passing `%Stripped_Name%` variable as parameter. But this parameter doesnt work. Any idea how I can pass this variable?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion
set CONFIGURATIONS=HAVING_FUN_WITH_COLLEGUES
for %%i in (%CONFIGURATIONS%) do (
set Original_Name=%%i
echo !Original_Name!
set Stripped_Name=!Original_Name:~0,-14!
echo !Stripped_Name!
call Strip_Batch.bat %%i %Stripped_Name%
if errorlevel 1 goto error_exit
) 

:the_end
endlocal
exit /b 0

:error_exit
endlocal
exit /b 1
```

Comment: `call Strip_Batch.bat %%i !Stripped_Name!`.

Comment: Sorry it did not work either too :-(

Comment: `call Strip_Batch.bat "%%i" "!Stripped_Name!"`  :)

Comment: Nope it did not work either too..see my second batch file. @echo off
setlocal enableextensions enableDelayedExpansion

set Param1 = MyName_%1
set Param2 = MyName_%2

echo Param1 : %Param1%
echo Param2 : %Param2%
endlocal

Comment: Cool it works now with your first solution only..call Strip_Batch.bat %%i !Stripped_Name!....I was doing a mistake in my second batch script..Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

according to my comment I'd suggest first:

```
call Strip_Batch.bat %%i !Stripped_Name!
```

and second (better, works also for parameter with spaces):

```
call Strip_Batch.bat "%%i" "!Stripped_Name!"
```